# I would like to erase the previous point of the multiple lines of text

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to erase the point of beginning point , as shown below.

The name of the file aaa.txt.

```
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/blue.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/default.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/peachpuff.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/shine.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/slate.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/desert.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/README.txt
./usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/torte.vim
```

to

```
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/blue.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/default.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/peachpuff.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/shine.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/slate.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/desert.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/README.txt
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/torte.vim
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed

```
sed -e 's,^\./,/,' <inputfile >outputfile
```

(this only removes the "." if there is a "/" following, just in case incorrect data were provided).